# Drupal panels module is shown missing but installed

Tags: drupal, module, panels

I'm new to Drupal (v7.3.4) but so far install is ok except for **panels** module is shown to be "missing". It is in the modules folder with all other modules (the rest all show fine). I've reinstalled and no change.
I tried a lower version and I get a wrong version popup.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saving the panels folder in sites/all/modules and not the /modules folder.  If not, move panels to the correct folder.  Any modification to the core installation should be saved within /sites/all or sites/default.

If that is not the culprit, try clearing cache.

Comment: Yes, module in right folder. Clearing cache had no effect. Example of where Panels is missing: "Requires: Chaos tools (enabled), Panels (missing), Page manager (enabled), Advanced help (enabled)"

Comment: Is it possible that the module you downloaded from the project page was corrupt and didn't extract completely.  If you look in the panels folder in your modules directory, are all the files and folders there?

Comment: Yes, all there. It is quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had same with other module - make sure that you have exact one panels.module file in your modules folder. Maybe you made two copies? or maybe you did /panels/panels by mistake? Also try to search for that file whole drupla folder

Comment: Thanks; I deleted the panels folder, and then reinstalled. Same result; dashboard shows it as "missing".